# Stability of the system without equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

What can be said about the stability of the system if it does not have an equilibrium point ?
e.g.

$x' = x^2 + y^2 + 1, \tag{1}$
$y' = x^2 - y^2, \tag{2}$

Comment: $x$ will grow forever. Unstable.

Comment: That does have equilibria if you allow complex numbers, namely $x,y=\pm i \sqrt{0.5}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing variables

$$
u = x+y\\
v = x-y
$$

results the system

$$
u' = \frac 12(u+v)^2+1\\
v' = \frac 12(u-v)^2+1
$$

so $u(t), v(t)$ grow without limit. An unstable system.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a motivation for Cesareo's answer. If you add/subtract both equations

$$\dot{x} + \dot{y} = 2x^2+1$$
$$\dot{x} - \dot{y} = 2y^2+1.$$

It should be obvious that we can introduce $u = x + y \implies \dot{u} = \dot{x}+\dot{y}$ and $v = x-y\implies \dot{v} = \dot{x} - \dot{y}$. The inverse substitution is given by $x = 0.5(u+v)$ and $y=0.5(u-v)$.

We will obtain the differential equations

$$\dot{u} = 0.5(u+v)^2+1$$
$$\dot{v} = 0.5(u-v)^2+1.$$